# List comprehension for returning multiple variables: Exclude '__name__', '__doc__' etc

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am declaring some global variables in a function and using a list comprehension to return all the values of the function in a single line of code. I only want to return the global variables created in the function, not system generated ones such as `__name__`, `__doc__`, `__package__` etc...how do I need to amend the below to achieve this?

**Function:**

```
def myfunc():

    global var1, var2, var3

    var1 = 'cat'
    var2 = 'dog'
    var3 = 'bird'

    return([name for name, val in globals().items()])

myfunc()
```

**Returned items:**

```
['__name__', '__doc__', '__package__', '__loader__', '__spec__', '__file__', '__cached__', '__builtins__', 'warnings', 'var1', 'var2', 'var3']
```

Comment: variables are already global, why do you need to return them?

Comment: I’m using them in another file

Comment: but why to not `return var1, var2, var3`?

Comment: How about `[name for name in globals() if not name.startswith('__')]`, but this also included `myfunc`, also just `return var1, var2, var3` is the right approach, and import `myfunc` in that file and call it

Answer (score 1):

Simply store all the system generated globals in a `set`

```
system_generated = {'__name__', '__doc__', '__package__', '__loader__', '__spec__', '__builtin__', '__builtins__', '_ih', '_oh', '_dh', 'In', 'Out', 'get_ipython', 'exit', 'quit', '_', '__', '___', '_i', '_ii', '_iii', '_i1', 'f', '_i2', '_i3', '_i4', '_i5', '_i6', '_i7', '_i8', '_i9', '_i10', '_i11', '_i12'}
```

Store all the globals in another `set` and return the difference.

```
all_globals = set(globals().keys())
```

Then return a `list` of the difference of the two sets, `system_generated` and `all_globals`.

```py
def myfunc():
    global var1, var2, var3

    var1 = 'cat'
    var2 = 'dog'
    var3 = 'bird'

    system_generated = {'__name__', '__doc__', '__package__', '__loader__', '__spec__', '__builtin__', '__builtins__', '_ih', '_oh', '_dh', 'In', 'Out', 'get_ipython', 'exit', 'quit', '_', '__', '___', '_i', '_ii', '_iii', '_i1', 'f', '_i2', '_i3', '_i4', '_i5', '_i6', '_i7', '_i8', '_i9', '_i10', '_i11', '_i12'}

    all_globals = set(globals().keys())

    return list(all_globals - system_generated)


myfunc()
```